# Query ActiveRecord with file permission type mathematical formula

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So standard file permissions are written in 0 to 7:

```
7 = 4+2+1 (read/write/execute)
6 = 4+2 (read/write)
5 = 4+1 (read/execute)
4 = 4 (read)
3 = 2+1 (write/execute)
2 = 2 (write)
1 = 1 (execute)
```

So lets say I want to save the permissions on a record the same way.  How do I place a query/scope on records that permit "read" permissions.

For example `4 == :record_permission % (4+1)` should return all readable by permission records.

Comment: You could create 7 scopes, 1 for each permissions. eg `scope :rwx, where(record_permission: 7)`

Comment: Are you saying there's no mathematical computation search?

Comment: `scope :read_access where(permission: [4..7])`

Comment: I like your answer Amit. That is a good solution.  Also for execute permission it could be `where(permission: [1,3,5,7])`

Comment: @Dan, I understand your question now. Amit's suggestion is very good.